# Decomposing partial fraction with a denominator negative quadratic expression $-x^2$

Tags: partial-fractions

${5x+4\over -x^2-x+2}$

My solution:

${5x+4\over -x^2-x+2}$

$= {5x+4\over -(x-1)(x+2)}$

$= {A\over (x-1)} + {B\over (x+2)}$

$= {3\over -(x-1)} + {2\over -(x+2)}$

$= -{3\over x-1} -{2\over x+2}$

Can I multiply both fractions by -1 as follows:

Rather than writing:

$ -{3\over x-1} -{2\over x+2}$

I could multiply the first fraction denominator by -1
${3\over -1*(x-1)} = {3\over 1-x}$

ditto for the second fraction to get:

${2\over -1* (x+2)} = {2\over -x-2}$

Are my solutions correct ?

Comment: It is true that $-\frac{a}{b} =\frac{-a}{b} = \frac{a}{-b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are correct : $$\frac{5x+4}{-x^2-x+2}=\frac{3}{1-x}\color{red}{+}\frac{2}{-x-2}.$$